# Unable to add a new version of iOS App in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

App Store Connect is throwing error when i try to add new ios App Version i.e, "An error has occurred. Try again later." I also tried different version values but it's not accepting.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try contacting apple's support team.

Comment: The error was gone after 3 days. I guess the solution is to just wait it out.

Comment: @AnatolyLubarsky same error, did you get it solved?

Comment: I had the same error. I wrote to support for help, no reply was received but the issue was gone 2 days later.

Comment: @Peter The error got resolved after 3 days. I tried different browsers, etc. Not sure what was going on.

Comment: @AnatolyLubarsky Same for me, resolved after 4-5 days. I wrote to support, but did not get a response, so I don't know if it resolved itself, or if support fixed it.

Comment: I also got the same issue while adding a new version in Appstore Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when adding a new version. I **solved** it by uploading a new build and skipping one version.

For example:

> if you are trying to add version 1.1.2, try adding 1.1.4
> instead